# nodejs to <video> streaming using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5-video, webrtc

I am currently using nodejs and express to stream video to  tags simply by waiting for app.get on the video tag src address and then using res.writeHead and res.write to provide the data.

I would like to be able to do the something similar but with lower latency using WebRTC. However, I am bit confused as to how to achieve this and haven't really found any good information resource.

Can anyone recommend any good examples, nodejs packages etc... that might be helpful?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
// Nodejs Server

rtcServer.on('connection', function(connection) {
    var videoSource = getVideoDataSource();
    videoSource.on('data', function(data) {
       connection.write(data);
    });
});
rtcServer.listen(8000);
```

-

```
// HTML Client

<video src="???:8000"/>
```

Comment: Server-side WebRTC is a nightmare.  I've never been able to get it working, after dropping months of work into it.  There is one guy who exported part of Chromium into a Node.js module, but any time I use his binary I get a segfault, and anytime I try to build my own binary, I find that libjingle and such in Chromium have been moved and his code doesn't compile anymore.  And, I can't figure out what version of Chromium was used in the first place.  I can't find the repo now, or I would send you a link so you could try.  Maybe you would have better luck than me.

Comment: Hi @ronag, Brad Have you had any luck pushing this further?